# Check if a file exists with Lua

Tags: file-io, lua, file-exists

How can I check if a file exists using Lua?

Comment: @Mitch as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340230/check-if-directory-exists-in-lua ?

Comment: @tonio - I guess more as in http://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.html

Comment: @Liutauras that is even close to a real answer. I only did a quick check only on so

Comment: Hi,

Thx for the quick respond.
I am doing: assert(io.input(fileName), "Error opening file")

But when i give a dummy filename, i don't get the error message : "Error opening file".

The message i get is: "bad argument #1 to 'input' (/pfrm2.0/share/lua/5.1/db/fake.dbdl: No such file or directory)"

any thoughts ?

Comment: Yoni, I understand you just joined SO. Welcome. Few things to mention. 1) Don't answer your own question with a new question. 2) Try to search around (Google is your friend) for more info and only if you are completely stuck ask here. This I believe will make you a better developer.

Comment: The reason you get "bad argument#1 to 'input'" is that input in Lua only takes one argument and you are passing 2. Plus you should assert io.open not input.

Comment: Hi Liutauras, i will take more notice for next time, sorry for that.

Comment: Also, i've change to io.open and it works now. Thank you

Comment: No problem Yoni. Thanks for sorting out your question. It just looks nicer now. Isn't why we love SO. Because it's nice.

Answer (score 125):

Try

```
function file_exists(name)
   local f=io.open(name,"r")
   if f~=nil then io.close(f) return true else return false end
end
```

but note that this code only tests whether the file can be opened for reading.

Comment: Note: If the file is a directory, this method returns false

Answer (score 10):

Using plain Lua, the best you can do is see if a file can be opened for read, as per LHF.  This is almost always good enough.  But if you want more, load the [Lua POSIX library](https://github.com/rrthomas/luaposix) and check if `posix.stat(`*path*`)` returns non-`nil`.

Comment: [LuaFileSystem](http://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem) works on Windows too. Use `lfs.attributes(path,'mode')`

Answer (score 8):

Lua 5.1:

```
function file_exists(name)
   local f = io.open(name, "r")
   return f ~= nil and io.close(f)
end
```

Answer (score 6):

I will quote myself from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340230/check-if-directory-exists-in-lua/21637668#21637668)

I use these (but I actually check for the error):

```
require("lfs")
-- no function checks for errors.
-- you should check for them

function isFile(name)
    if type(name)~="string" then return false end
    if not isDir(name) then
        return os.rename(name,name) and true or false
        -- note that the short evaluation is to
        -- return false instead of a possible nil
    end
    return false
end

function isFileOrDir(name)
    if type(name)~="string" then return false end
    return os.rename(name, name) and true or false
end

function isDir(name)
    if type(name)~="string" then return false end
    local cd = lfs.currentdir()
    local is = lfs.chdir(name) and true or false
    lfs.chdir(cd)
    return is
end
```

os.rename(name1, name2) will rename name1 to name2. Use the same name and nothing should change (except there is a badass error). If everything worked out good it returns true, else it returns nil and the errormessage. If you dont want to use lfs you cant differentiate between files and directories without trying to open the file (which is a bit slow but ok).

So without LuaFileSystem

```
-- no require("lfs")

function exists(name)
    if type(name)~="string" then return false end
    return os.rename(name,name) and true or false
end

function isFile(name)
    if type(name)~="string" then return false end
    if not exists(name) then return false end
    local f = io.open(name)
    if f then
        f:close()
        return true
    end
    return false
end

function isDir(name)
    return (exists(name) and not isFile(name))
end
```

It looks shorter, but takes longer...
Also open a file is a it risky

Have fun coding!

Comment: How are errors from os.rename handled regarding renaming read-only files?

Comment: What are the risks in simply opening a file from lua?

Comment: @carpii If you try to open a locked file and read from it it may result in an error (you still want to know whether its a file or not). Same goes for directories (if diectory lock is supported on the host).

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson What do you mean? With 'badass error' i did not mean something you could fix by code. However, AFAIK you can use pcall to capture them. Handling might be complicated and uninformative error messages could be returned.

Comment: For the lfs case, [use `lfs.attributes` to query the file/folder without renaming or opening it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33289219/79125).

Answer (score 6):

If you're using [Premake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premake) and LUA version 5.3.4:

```
if os.isfile(path) then
    ...
end
```

Comment: this is not official function, it's function of premake

Comment: @Konrad AH. My mistake. premake is all I use lua for. :(

Comment: No problem mate

Answer (score 5):

If you are willing to use `lfs`, you can use `lfs.attributes`. It will return `nil` in case of error:

```
require "lfs"

if lfs.attributes("non-existing-file") then
    print("File exists")
else
    print("Could not get attributes")
end
```

Although it can return `nil` for other errors other than a non-existing file, if it doesn't return `nil`, the file certainly exists.

Comment: To only check for files (not directories) you can use `lfs.attributes(path, "mode") == "file"`

Answer (score 3):

For sake of completeness: You may also just try your luck with `path.exists(filename)`. I'm not sure which Lua distributions actually have this `path` namespace (**update**: [Penlight](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight/blob/master/lua/pl/path.lua)), but at least it is included in Torch:

```
$ th

  ______             __   |  Torch7
 /_  __/__  ________/ /   |  Scientific computing for Lua.
  / / / _ \/ __/ __/ _ \  |  Type ? for help
 /_/  \___/_/  \__/_//_/  |  https://github.com/torch
                          |  http://torch.ch

th> path.exists(".gitignore")
.gitignore  

th> path.exists("non-existing")
false
```

`debug.getinfo(path.exists)` tells me that its source is in `torch/install/share/lua/5.1/pl/path.lua` and it is implemented as follows:

```
--- does a path exist?.
-- @string P A file path
-- @return the file path if it exists, nil otherwise
function path.exists(P)
    assert_string(1,P)
    return attrib(P,'mode') ~= nil and P
end
```

Comment: That would be [Penlight](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight/blob/master/lua/pl/path.lua), and it uses [LuaFileSystem](http://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/) behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3):

An answer which is windows only checks for files and folders, and also requires no additional packages. It returns `true` or `false`.

```
io.popen("if exist "..PathToFileOrFolder.." (echo 1)"):read'*l'=='1'
```

> **io.popen(...):read'*l'** - executes a command in the command prompt and reads the result from the CMD stdout
>
> **if exist** - CMD command to check if an object exists
>
> **(echo 1)** - prints 1 to stdout of the command prompt

Comment: This opens a briefly visible console window, so I'd advise against this idea.

Answer (score 2):

An answer which is windows only checks for files and folders, and also requires no additional packages. It returns true or false.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the 'paths' package. [Here](https://github.com/torch/paths)'s the link to the package

Then in Lua do:

```
require 'paths'

if paths.filep('your_desired_file_path') then
    print 'it exists'
else
    print 'it does not exist'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the most ideal as I do not know your specific purpose for this or if you have a desired implementation in mind, but you can simply open the file to check for its existence.

```
local function file_exists(filename)
    local file = io.open(filename, "r")
    if (file) then
        -- Obviously close the file if it did successfully open.
        file:close()
        return true
    end
    return false
end
```

`io.open` returns `nil` if it fails to open the file. As a side note, this is why it is often used with `assert` to produce a helpful error message if it is unable to open the given file. For instance:

```
local file = assert(io.open("hello.txt"))
```

If the file `hello.txt` does not exist, you should get an error similar to `stdin:1: hello.txt: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 0):

For library solution, you can use either `paths` or `path`.

From the [official document](https://github.com/torch/paths/blob/master/doc/filenames.md) of `paths`:

> paths.filep(path)
>
> Return a boolean indicating whether path refers to an existing file.
>
> paths.dirp(path)
>
> Return a boolean indicating whether path refers to an existing directory.

Although the names are a little bit strange, you can certainly use `paths.filep()` to check whether a path exists and it is a file. Use `paths.dirp()` to check whether it exists and it is a directory. Very convenient.

If you prefer `path` rather than `paths`, you can use `path.exists()` with `assert()` to check the existence of a path, getting its value at the same time. Useful when you are building up path from pieces.

```lua
prefix = 'some dir'

filename = assert(path.exist(path.join(prefix, 'data.csv')), 'data.csv does not exist!')
```

If you just want to check the boolean result, use `path.isdir()` and `path.isfile()`. Their purposes are well-understood from their names.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this?

```
function exist(file)
  local isExist = io.popen(
    '[[ -e '.. tostring(file) ..' ]] && { echo "true"; }')
  local isIt = isExist:read("*a")
  isExist:close()
  isIt = string.gsub(isIt, '^%s*(.-)%s*$', '%1')
  if isIt == "true" then
    return true
  end
  return false
end

if exist("myfile") then
  print("hi, file exists")
else
  print("bye, file does not exist")
end
```

Comment: I get `'[[' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Its working on my unix machine. What OS are you using ? `type [[` should say `[[ is a shell keyword`

Comment: @RakibFiha he using windows based on the error message and it work on my Linux machine

Answer (score 0):

If you use LOVE, you can use the function `love.filesystem.exists('NameOfFile')`, replacing `NameOfFile` with the file name.
This returns a Boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

if you are like me exclusively on Linux, BSD any UNIX type you can use this:

```lua
function isDir(name)
    if type(name)~="string" then return false end
    return os.execute('if [ -d "'..name..'" ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi')
end

function isFile(name)
    if type(name)~="string" then return false end
    return os.execute('if [ -f "'..name..'" ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi')
end
```

Actually this looks even better:

```lua
function isDir(name)
    if type(name)~="string" then return false end
    return os.execute('test -d '..name)
end

function isFile(name)
    if type(name)~="string" then return false end
    return os.execute('test -f '..name)
end

function exists(name)
    if type(name)~="string" then return false end
    return os.execute('test -e '..name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Lua 5.4:

```
function file_exists(name)
   local f <close> = io.open(name, "r")
   return f ~= nil
end
```

Answer (score -7):

```
IsFile = function(path)
print(io.open(path or '','r')~=nil and 'File exists' or 'No file exists on this path: '..(path=='' and 'empty path entered!' or (path or 'arg "path" wasn\'t define to function call!')))
end

IsFile()
IsFile('')
IsFIle('C:/Users/testuser/testfile.txt')
```

Looks good for testing your way. :)