# how to check if a file exists in lua - when you don't have the full file name?

Tags: lua

I have a situation where I don't know the complete name of a file but I need to search for it to see if it exists.  the part of the file name that I don't know is a sequence number at the end of the name. 
For example, the file name looks like this:

myfile.1234567890.12.xff

the ".12" part is what I don't know.  However, I just need to know if any files starting with "myfile.1234567890" and ending with ".xff" exist.

How would i accomplish this in lua? 
thanks.

Comment: Duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990990/lua-check-if-a-file-exists

Comment: @user1929959, it is not. dot is looking for glob() in lua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an implementation of glob function in Lua at this [link](https://github.com/davidm/lua-glob-pattern). But you could just iterate through the list of all files in the folder and check them against your pattern. You could use [LuaFileSystem lfs.dir()](http://keplerproject.github.com/luafilesystem/) to get the list.

Answer (score 2):

Version for Windows.
No external libraries.

```
local function recursive_search(path, OS_filemask, filename_pattern, search_for_dirs, only_top_level)
   path = path:gsub('/', '\\'):gsub('\\*$', '\\', 1)
   OS_filemask = OS_filemask or '*.*'
   filename_pattern = filename_pattern or '.*'
   local arr = {}
   local pipe = io.popen((search_for_dirs and 'dir /b/ad "' or 'dir /b/a-d "')..path..OS_filemask..'" 2> nul')
   for f in pipe:lines() do
      if f:lower():match('^'..filename_pattern..'$') then
         table.insert(arr, path..f)
      end
   end
   pipe:close()
   if not only_top_level then
      for _, path in ipairs(recursive_search(path, nil, nil, true, true)) do
         for _, f in ipairs(recursive_search(path, OS_filemask, filename_pattern, search_for_dirs)) do
            table.insert(arr, f)
         end
      end
   end
   return arr
end

-- Find all number-named JPEG picures in C:\Games
-- OS filemask can't filter it properly, use Lua pattern to restrict search conditions
for _, f in ipairs(recursive_search('C:\\Games', '*.jp*g', '%d+%.jpe?g')) do
   print(f)
end

-- Find all folders in C:\WINDOWS with 32 in its name
-- OS filemask is enough here
for _, f in ipairs(recursive_search('C:\\WINDOWS', '*32*', nil, true)) do
   print(f)
end

-- myfile.1234567890.12.xff
for _, f in ipairs(recursive_search('C:\\', 'myfile.1234567890.*.xff', 'myfile%.1234567890%.%d+%.xff')) do
   print(f)
end
```